# How does the interaction between individual electrons of beams affects the diffraction pattern?

Tags: waves, electrons, diffraction, wave-particle-duality

Consider the diffraction of an electron beam.

- How does the interaction between individual electrons of beams affects the diffraction pattern?
- If it really affects the diffraction pattern, then is it possible mathematically to obtain characteristics of diffraction pattern just by using parameters of electron *interactions* & *system* size?

Comment: There is definitely a space charge effect on the diffraction pattern which will destroy the patters at high beam density/current. Can this be modeled? Yes, but it's probably not completely trivial. I would suggest to consult the literature on electron and ion beam microscopy and patterning methods for the semiconductor industry. That's probably the most likely source of useful papers containing the analysis of the problem. You may also find something of interest in accelerator beam physics.

Comment: see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_diffraction .an electron-electron interaction might give a different intensity pattern to a single electron at a time impinging on a crystal. I do not see that the last sentence has any connection to this.

Comment: In a TEM under normal operating voltages and currents, there is on average only one electron in the column at a time. Enough current for space charge effects and your sample will melt.

Comment: To zeroth order, space charge effects will increase the divergence of the electron beam. This angular spread before hitting the sample will result in a smearing of the diffraction pattern by a similar angular spread. Nothing more, really.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209402/in-diffraction-process-how-to-describe-the-edge-in-the-sense-of-particle-wave-d

Answer (score -5):

If electrons were to interact with each other (causing them to accelerate)then one or all of them would emit photons and photons definitely effect the paths of a free electrons. I have written about this at the end of my paper on my site at the top of my page.

Comment: Unless your paper is peer-reviewed it's not an acceptable reference (not to mention that you failed to provide the link)

Comment: But what about the answer? Wouldn't the photons affect the electrons?